# 'Missing' cookies in python requests response

Tags: python, curl, cookies, python-requests

I have a working cURL command, which gets a number of cookies from this particular (alfresco, although I don't think this is particularly an alfresco issue), however when I try and encode the same request with python requests, I get only one cookie.

The cURL request is

```
curl -v --junk-session-cookies -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --cookie-jar cookies.txt --cookie cookies.txt -H 'Origin: http://<url>' -D headers.txt -e ';auto' -X POST -d @credentials http://<url>/share/page/dologin
```

And the python is

```
r=s.post('%s/share/page/dologin' % <url>,
           data=credentials, allow_redirects=False)
```

where

```
s.headers
Out[121]: {'Origin': <url>, 'Host' :<url>, 'referer':<url> , 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.4.1 CPython/2.7.5+ Linux/3.11.0-26-generic','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

designed to closely match the headers that cURL is sending in.
The `allow_redirects=False` is there to mirror the lack of the `-L` option.

cURL yields:

`Added cookie JSESSIONID="<removed>" for domain 10.12.3.166, path /share/, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=<removed>; Path=/share/; HttpOnly
* Added cookie alfLogin="<removed>" for domain 10.12.3.166, path /share, expire 1413289198
< Set-Cookie: alfLogin=<removed>; Expires=Tue, 14-Oct-2014 12:19:58 GMT; Path=/share
* Added cookie alfUsername3="<obf>" for domain 10.12.3.166, path /share, expire 1413289198
< Set-Cookie: alfUsername3=<obf>; Expires=Tue, 14-Oct-2014 12:19:58 GMT; Path=/share`

Whereas I only get the JSESSIONID cookie in requests.

**Update**
I foolishly failed to include the headers sent in the cURL command, and those received. 
Those sent were

```
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: <url>
> Accept: */*
> Referer: 
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Origin: <url>
> Content-Length: 44
```

And the headers sent back are

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=<rem>; Path=/share/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: alfLogin=<rem>; Expires=Tue, 14-Oct-2014 12:19:58 GMT; Path=/share
Set-Cookie: alfUsername3=<rem>; Expires=Tue, 14-Oct-2014 12:19:58 GMT; Path=/share
Location: <url>/share
```

The headers sent back to requests are

```
{'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'set-cookie': 'JSESSIONID=<rem>; Path=/share/; HttpOnly', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'connection': 'close', 'date': 'Wed, 08 Oct 2014 08:54:53 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'}
```

Comment: I don't see the Content_type in your requests.

Comment: Well spotted @VincentBeltman, however it changed nothing in the response.

Comment: The content type header will be set correctly by `requests` *anyway*, provided `credentials` is a dictionary.

Comment: It is *extremely* hard to discern why the server responds differently here; servers are essentially black boxes. There is nothing special about your `requests` setup in that regard. I'd leave out the `Host` header, and manage the `Referer` header per request sent, and test against http://httpbin.org to see exactly what headers are sent by both options to try and see what might be missing, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, httpbin.org revealed many differences. Could you explain a bit more @MartijnPieters what you mean by "manage the `Referer` header per request sent,"

Comment: @DavidBoshton: you have it set on the session, I'd use the `headers` argument to `s.post()` instead.

Comment: There *may* be an issue with the multiple set-cookie headers not being represented properly on `r.headers`. What does `s.cookies.keys()` tells you are set?

Comment: Can you include the output of `r.request.headers` please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the "Host" header and set the referer field to be ''. I then got all the cookies I needed, so thanks to all the helpful comments.

Comment: Useful to supply an example of the `requests` fix.